# How to bind component id as parent relative path to HTML element inside template

Tags: javascript, html, angular, material-design-lite

I am using Angular2 RC1 version and Material Design Lite.
I am going to implement an independent grid component.
A custom property called Id is used to identify the component.

```
export class GridComponent {

  @Input() public id: string;

}
```

I am facing the problem when I bind Id property to the 'for' attribute of UL tag. Like below code snippet:

```
<button class="mdl-button" id="{{id}}-viewColumn">
    <i class="material-icons">view_column</i>
</button>

<ul class="mdl-menu" for="{{id}}-viewColumn">
    <li *ngFor="xxx">
    </li>
</ul>
```

Then error says that 'Can't bind to 'for' since it isn't a known native property'.
But I have to use 'UL' tag.  Above 'UL' code is following the https://getmdl.io/components/#menus-section.
I am wondering that how would you handle this case?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: `for` is a property of `<label>`.  what are you trying to do with this?  If you want to add a custom property, you'll have to create your own component that will contain and apply changes to its own `<ul>`.

Comment: @ps2goat, thanks for your reply. For I am using Material Design Lite as UI framework, I think I have to follow the code sample provided by https://getmdl.io/components/#menus-section.

Comment: Seems limited by MDL here, is that right that I have to use 'UL' tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It obviously has to be added as an attribute instead of as property.

Use

```
<ul [attr.for]="id"
```

or

```
<ul attr.for="{{id}}"
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. <ul attr.for="{{id}}"  works for me.

Comment: Both do the same. `{{id}}` binds the stringified value of `id` but attributes can hold strings only anyway, therefore `[attr.for]="id"` has the same end result. If you bind to a property and `id` is not a string, then `for="{{id}}"` and `[for]="id"` differ because only the later passes the value unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

there is no for property on the native element. can you just add label inside ul ? 
`<label [attr.for]="{{id}}-viewColumn">`.

Comment: Yes. As we all know, property 'for' is usually used on 'label'. But in this case, I think I have to use 'UL'. Please kindly take a look at https://getmdl.io/components/#menus-section.  Seems limited by MDL here.